# Integration of $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$

Tags: integration

Integrating $$\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$
I was told that I should not write it as $\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2x}$, can anyone enlighten me?
Must the $\arctan$ form be used?

Comment: Did you try differentiating $\ln(x^2+1)/2x$? You don't get $1/(x^2 + 1)$. You already seem to know that $\arctan x$ is the correct answer, so I'm not quite sure what your question is.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think of it as "using the arctangent form."  The arctangent is not a form of the correct answer, it *is* the correct answer.  Your question makes it sound like you think $\dfrac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2x}$ and $\arctan x$ are different forms of the same thing, but they're not.

To show that $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dx}{x^2+1} \ne \dfrac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2x} + C$, we can differentiate the RHS and see that it does not equal $\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$.

\begin{align}
  \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2x} + C\right)
    &= \frac{2x \cdot \frac{1}{x^2+1} \cdot 2x - \ln(x^2+1) \cdot 2}{(2x)^2}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{\frac{4x^2}{x^2+1} - 2\ln(x^2+1)}{4x^2}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{4x^2 - 2(x^2+1)\ln(x^2+1)}{4x^2(x^2+1)}\\[0.3cm]
    &\ne \frac{1}{x^2+1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d(\arctan(x))}{dx} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ but the derivative of $$\frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{(2x)}$$ is $$ \frac{1}{1+x^2} - \frac{\ln(x^2+1)}{2x^2} $$.

May be you forget how to find derivative of fraction.